# Haskell Program error: pattern match failure

Tags: haskell

```
genProbPairs (((a,b,c),d):xs) (((e,f),g):ys) =
  if a==e && b==f
  then [((a,b,c),d/g)]++genProbPairs xs (((e,f),g):ys)
  else genProbPairs (((a,b,c),d):xs) ys

genProbPairs [] _ =[]
```

I made Haskell Function that divides the frequency of 3 words occurrence with the frequency of the occurrence of the first 2 words. For example, here's a test case:

```
genProbPairs
  [ (("the","man","is"),1)
  , (("man","is","the"),1)
  , (("is","the","man"),1)
  , (("the","man","."),1)
  , (("man",".","the"),1)
  , ((".","the","man"),1)
  , (("the","man","saw"),1)]
  [ (("man","is"),1)
  , (("is","the"),1)
  , (("man","."),1)
  , ((".","the"),1)
  , (("the","man"),3)
  , (("man","saw"),1)]
```

The expected answer is:

```
[ (("the","man","is"),0.333333333333333)
, (("man","is","the"),1.0)
, (("is","the","man"),1.0)
, (("the","man","."),0.333333333333333)
, (("man",".","the"),1.0)
, ((".","the","man"),1.0)
, (("the","man","saw"),0.333333333333333)
]
```

I am having a problem when I run that it doesn't divide and an error occurs with the following message:

```
Program error: pattern match failure: genProbPairs [(("the","man","is"),1),(("man","is","the"),1),(("is","the","man"),1),(("the","man","."),1),(("man",".","the"),1),((".","the","man"),1),(("the","man","\rsaw"),1)] []
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: The problem probably has to do with how your function doesn't have a case for the first list not being empty while the second one is.

Comment: Formatting your code is a kindness to the people who can help you, and future people who benefit from your question.

Comment: when i did so it returned an empty list only

Comment: @MichaelLitchard i am sorry it's my first time to post on StackOverFlow

Comment: I just formatted it for you @OmarEhab. I wasn’t quite sure in a couple of places what you were asking though, so feel free to undo my edit if I accidentally changed your question.

Comment: @OmarEhab You’re welcome!

Comment: Duplode tells you where to start. Maybe heed his advice and see what happens next?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard it is not the case

Comment: @OmarEhab How do you know? That seems to be the only way to get a pattern match error from your program.

Comment: it solved the pattern match error problem but it outputs an empty list always not the expected result

Answer (score 1):

The two patterns your function matches are

```hs
genProbPairs (((a,b,c),d):xs) (((e,f),g):ys) = ...
genProbPairs [] _ = ...
```

The first definition of the function assumes that the second list will match the pattern

```
(((e,f),g):ys)
```

The use of `:` in this pattern means that the pattern will *only* match a list that contains at least one element. If the list is empty then this pattern will not match. But if the second list is empty and the first list is *not* empty then neither definition of the function is usable and your program will crash! In order to fix this, you need to add another definition—one that looks like

```hs
genProbPairs _ [] = ...
```

What exactly the `...` needs to be replaced with is something you need to figure out based on the requirements of the problem.

Comment: it removed the pattern match problem but the expected result wasn't the same it returns an empty list

Comment: @OmarEhab You should edit your question to add your updated code and a description of how its behavior is different from what you want. (Please *add* this information instead of replacing what’s already there!)